# Timestamp check if older than 12 hours

Tags: php, timestamp

How can I check if a timestamp is older than 12 hours?

I need to make a link work for 12 hours, after that I need to display an error message.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: What is the code you are using for getting the timestamp from the database?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$dateFromDatabase = strtotime("2012-12-04 12:05:04");
$dateTwelveHoursAgo = strtotime("-12 hours");

if ($dateFromDatabase >= $dateTwelveHoursAgo) {
    // less than 12 hours ago
}
else {
    // more than 12 hours ago
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**#1. Do compare in database :**

If you have *TIMESTAMP* field:

```
timestampField < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - 3600*12)
```

If you have *DATETIME* field:

```
datetimeField < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
```

---

**#2. Do compare in PHP :**

```
$c = new DateTime;
$d = new DateTime('you timestamp or datetime');
if ($c < $d->modify('-12 hour')) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean a unix-timestamp. If so you can apply simple math:

```
// a unix-timestamp is the time since 1970 in seconds
// 60 seconds = 1 minute, 60 minutes = 1 hour, 12 hours
// so this calculates the current timestamp - 12 hours and checks
// if 12 hours ago the timestamp from your database lay in the future
if ( $timestamp > (time() - 60*60*12) ) {
    // show your link
} else {
    // 12 hours are up
    // give your error message
}
```

If your database returns a formatted date (like mysql with the timestamp/date field types) you have to use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get a unix timestamp first.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have an unique key you’re using in a download link. Simply include the timestamp clause in your `WHERE` statement:

```
<?php

$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-12 hours'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `key` = :key AND `created` > :timestamp";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':key', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':timestamp', $timestamp, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchObject();
```